Test step of VAE returns only 0s
I'm jumping back into a project I stopped working on last year (mostly). I had already encountered this issue, and this answer solved it back then. I am currently running basically the exact script from that answer, but now during training, I'm back to getting all 0s for validation losses, both KL and reconstruction.
history = var_autoencoder.fit( x_train, x_train, epochs=1000, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test), 
                 callbacks=kcb.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=30, restore_best_weights=True) )

Epoch 1/1000
107/107 [==============================] - 3s 30ms/step - loss: 118.1165 - reconstruction_loss: 117.0647 - kl_loss: 1.0518 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_reconstruction_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_kl_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/1000
107/107 [==============================] - 3s 30ms/step - loss: 104.4190 - reconstruction_loss: 103.7018 - kl_loss: 0.7172 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_reconstruction_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_kl_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/1000
107/107 [==============================] - 3s 30ms/step - loss: 103.2905 - reconstruction_loss: 102.5077 - kl_loss: 0.7828 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_reconstruction_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_kl_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/1000
107/107 [==============================] - 3s 31ms/step - loss: 101.7333 - reconstruction_loss: 100.8803 - kl_loss: 0.8530 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_reconstruction_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_kl_loss: 0.0000e+00

Sample dataset and full script can be found here

In this example they also update the metrics in the test step. If I see it correctly, this is not in your test_step()

@mhenning that seems to work yeah. If you type it up in an answer, I'll accept it. When is that article from?

Will do. Regarding the date, the article was last updated on 2024-04-12 UTC, as marked at the bottom of the page. I also looked into the internet archive, and there the page was first snapshot'ed at 25.08.2020. At this date, the part with the test_step was already included.

In this example from the Tensorflow pages they also updated the metrics in the test_step function:
# Update the metrics.
for metric in self.metrics:
    if metric.name != "loss":
        metric.update_state(y, y_pred)

Without the update, the evaluation metrics will stay at its initialized value zero.
